# Does anyone have any example of Python (with RDFLIB, if possible) code for comparing 2 RDF files that works for file size greater than 2 GB?

Tags: file, comparison, rdf

I found problems comparing large RDF files (2 GB each, for example), as I used RDFLIB library (python) in memory mode.
I discovered the possibility of using Oxigraph (external store), so would be possible not to use memory but rather a repository. But I found an encode incompatibility problem when using the graph.add() method.
Would anyone have an indication of more complete RDFLIB and Oxigraph documentation?
Does anyone have any example of Python (with RDFLIB, if possible) code for comparing 2 RDF files that works for file size greater than 2 GB?

I discovered the possibility of using Oxigraph (external store), so would be possible not to use memory but rather a repository.

Comment: What specific problems were encountered with RDFLib? Alternatively, you can use any graph database on the market (GraphDB, Virtuoso, et. al) and use sparql to check. There are also other libraries like Jena and cli tools that support diffing

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323636/comparing-sparql-graphs
https://librdf.org/raptor/